# Surface Laptop 2: unable to click on anything on the right two inches of the screen

Tags: windows-10, laptop, microsoft-surface

My Surface is six months old and works great. Within the past few weeks, the strangest thing has arisen.

If I have a window, say notepad (but this is for any app), and the right edge of the notepad form moves into the right two inches of the screen, I am unable to click the control buttons on the title bar with either the track pad or the touch screen.

If I drag it out of the right two inches, I can use both the track pad and the touch screen to press the minimize/close buttons on the title bar.

This affects all applications.

I checked Device Manager, and all drivers look happy (no warning indicators).

I tried updating the video driver, but it says my current driver is up to date  (it is from Sept 2018).

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try calibrating your screen: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023476/surface-what-to-try-if-touchscreen-doesnt-work

Comment: I'm not sure if these steps are what did it, but I followed them and the problem seems to have gone away for now.
I'll add that the problem seems to come and go pretty randomly but is very annoying when it happens.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: it’s no problem - i’ll type it up as an actual answer a bit later so it can be accepted and we can close the question. glad it’s working!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a calibration issue if neither the mouse or touchscreen can click on a specific portion of the screen separated by a vertical line - but I will go ahead and include some additional steps that might be beneficial to try in this situation:

### Check for Windows and Surface updates

1. Go to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Check for updates.
2. After the updates are installed, at the right under Windows Update, select Restart now. Your Surface may restart several times, depending on the updates that were installed.

### Reset touch calibration to the default settings

> Warning!
>
> Do not manually recalibrate your touch settings. Surface devices come from the factory already calibrated and optimized for pen and touch input to ensure the best possible operation. If someone recalibrated your Surface manually or its default calibration changed for any reason, this might cause your device issue.

1. In the search box on the taskbar, enter calibrate, and then select Calibrate the screen for pen or touch input from the list of results. (With a mouse, select Start, then select Calibrate the screen for pen or touch input.)
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you select Reset, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  (If you're using a mouse, select Reset.) If Reset is unavailable (appears dimmed), your Surface touch calibration is already at the factory settings.
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you select Yes, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and follow the onscreen instructions to recalibrate your Surface. (If you're using a mouse, select Yes, and then follow the onscreen instructions to recalibrate your Surface.)
4. Restart your Surface and test the touchscreen to check whether it responds appropriately.

Reference: [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023476/surface-what-to-try-if-touchscreen-doesnt-work)